# Converting node names with alphanumeric names to numeric in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have node names in neo4j with names something like "abc124","abcd124","xyz678","zxyz678" etc

In the above node names,abc124 & abcd124 have same numbers(ID/accnt number)-124,so I need to merge these nodes which have same IDs/accnt number. The logic which I'm trying is separate the alphanumeric node names to numbers and then use apoc procedure to merge the nodes

I'm not able to find any function which removes the character part from the node names

I tried toInteger but does not work

```
RETURN toInteger('42AB')
```

So my input node names are "abc124","abcd124","xyz678","zxyz678"
So my output nodes names I would want is 124,124,678,678....

Comment: What is the pattern of id/acc number in name? Is it always last 3 digits or something else?

Comment: Only pattern in it is the account number is followed by 'ACCNT:".It is something like "XYZ.........ACCNT: <account no>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APOC function [apoc.text.regexGroups](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_overview_text_functions) may be helpful.

For example:

```
RETURN TOINTEGER(apoc.text.regexGroups('abc123', '\\d+')[0][0])
```

returns:

```
123
```

[UPDATE]

To merge `Foo` nodes whose `name` properties end in the same digits, you can also use [apoc.refactor.mergeNodes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#graph-refactoring) to help with the node merging (you may also want to specify some of its documented config options, depending on your needs).

```
MATCH (f:Foo)
WITH f, TOINTEGER(apoc.text.regexGroups(f.name, '\\d+')[0][0]) AS acct
WITH acct, COLLECT(f) AS foos
WHERE SIZE(foos) > 1
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(foos) YIELD node
RETURN acct
```

Comment: Can this work for all the nodes in the data.For example I have all the nodes like these,we might have to loop it using foreach clause in neo4j?

Comment: See my updated answer for an example of how to merge the nodes. I assume the nodes of interest have the `Foo` label.